# Azure Pipeline Parallelism option

Tags: azure-devops, parallel-processing, azure-pipelines

I am new to azure pipelines, started learning & in the process of creating my very 1st yaml pipeline.

My project is private, I am using a multi-stage templated pipeline, self-hosted as need to concurrently deploy a java web application to 7 VMs using mvn tomcat7 plugin run: command
so as to run selenium automation tests in parallel across all the VMs. A template pipeline which is called 7 times to deploy to all the VMs is such that it needs to stay running as
necessitated by the embedded tomcat instance on each of the VMs which in turn requires the ablitiy to have parallelism enabled, pay extra for to achieve this.

My question is; is there another way without having to pay extra for parallelism or turning my project to be a public one ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [parallel job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted).  Only job could execute publish tasks in parallel.

And from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#how-much-do-parallel-jobs-cost), you could use parallel job freely when you change your project to public. And the job can run for up to 360 minutes(6 hours).

You need is that under **Project Settings**--> **Overview**--> change **Visibility** to `public`.

[image]

After that, under pipeline, add the publish task for each new agent job. So that, you could executes the publish task in parallel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you the answer

Comment: i did not want to convert the project to public